# How to add wildcard search to my function in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, search, wildcard

Trying to understand my 1st laravel script and got stuck with a simple search function.

Two Problems.

1.) Search starts with the first letter only. Let's say I will find the entry 'Cats and Dogs' and I search with 'ats'. No result. But if I search with 'Cat' it's working.

2.) Space breaks the search. i.e. I search for 'Cats and' there will be no result. If I search for 'Cats' or 'and' it's working.

My function

```
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function products_modal(){
      $products = \App\Models\Product::select(DB::raw('CONCAT_WS( "", name, category, "") as name'), 'uuid')
      ->where('active', '1')
      ->orderBy('stock1', 'desc')
      ->lists('name', 'uuid');
        return view('products.products_modal', compact('products'));
    }
```

What I want is to be able to search for 'and Dogs' or 'ats' and find this entry.

I have the feeling I'm looking at the wrong part of my script.

Comment: You mean `->where('my_field','like','%ats%')` ?

Comment: Yes a simple like query. But as you can see in the code that I posted there is no where for the searched keyword. To be frank I don‘t know why the search is working. First time Laravel for me.

Comment: Ok what happens when you add the code above?

Comment: I'm getting all entries that include ats. This I know. But I don't know what the variable  of the search is. And why is it working without this statement in the way I described before?